# Vertical align of h2 tags inside several divs

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and several child divs inside it. I would like to get the top of each h2 tag be the same. Now it is not.

```
<div style="width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="float:left;top:0"><h2>L2</h2></div>
    gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg<br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="float:left:top:0"><h2>R1</h2></div>
    gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="float:left:top:0"><h2>W1</h2></div>
    gdgsdgsgsgsgs
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create an actual example, either via a snippet, or a jsfiddle. Also, your CSS doesn't make sense. `top` can't be used together with `float`- `top` is just used for positioning elements together with `position: absolute;` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your inline blocks to `vertical-align:top;` will solve the problem for you. Additionally i would like to point out that you have given colon(:) instead of semicolon in between the inline css properties of the divs inside the inline blocks. So, the final code should be as follows:

```
<div style="width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
        <div style="float:left;top:0">
            <h2>L2</h2>
        </div>
        gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg<br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
        <div style="float:left;top:0">
            <h2>R1</h2>
        </div>
        gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">
        <div style="float:left;top:0">
            <h2>W1</h2>
        </div>
        gdgsdgsgsgsgs
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I just changed the `style="float:left:top:0px"`

to `style="float:left;top:0px"`. You missed a **;** **semicolon**. and I added your content in another `<div>`.

```html
<div style="width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="float:left;top:0px"><h2>L2</h2></div>
    <div style="height:50px;">gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg<br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd</div>
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="float:left;top:0px"><h2>R1</h2></div>
    <div style="height:50px;">gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg</div>
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
    <div style="float:left;top:0px"><h2>W1</h2></div>
    <div style="height:50px;">gdgsdgsgsgsgs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you have gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg<br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd 3 times.

Comment: @xms: Can't understand your comment.

Comment: @xms : Check now..I have added height to the content div.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is to use display flex and flex styling in the parent div

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: baseline; justify-content:center; width: 100%;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle; padding: 16px;">
    <div style="float:left:top:0">
      <h2>L2</h2>
    </div>
    gdgsdgsgsgsgs
    <br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
    <br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle; padding: 16px;">
    <div style="float:left:top:0">
      <h2>R1</h2>
    </div>
    gdgsdgsgsgsgs
    <br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
  </div>

  <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle, padding: 16px;">
    <div style="float:left:top:0">
      <h2>W1</h2>
    </div>
    gdgsdgsgsgsgs
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `flex` and make `h2` and text container sibblings, `margin` should finalyze it:

```css
body> div,
body > div > div {
  display:flex;
}
body> div {
  justify-content:center;
}
body > div > div {
  padding:0 1em;
  flex-flow:column;
}
body > div > div >  h2 {
  margin:0;
  text-align:center
}
body > div > div > div {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>L2</h2>
    <div>gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg<br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>R1</h2>
    <div>gdgsdgsgsgsgs<br>gsgsgsgsdgsg</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>W1</h2>
    <div>
      gdgsdgsgsgsgs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

your code under my minimalistic example:

```css
body> div,
body > div > div {
  display:flex;
}
body> div {
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center
}
body > div > div {
  padding: 1em 0.125em;
  flex-flow:column;
}
body > div > div >  h2 {
  margin:0 0 0.75em;
}
body > div > div > div {
  margin:auto;
}
h2 {
  background:lightblue
}
h1 {
  font-size:1rem;
  color:tomato;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
```

```html
<h1>minimalistic flex layout version </h1>
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>L2</h2>
    <div>gdgsdgsgsgsgs
      <br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
      <br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>R1</h2>
    <div>gdgsdgsgsgsgs
      <br>gsgsgsgsdgsg</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>W1</h2>
    <div>
      gdgsdgsgsgsgs</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<h1>below your code </h1>
<section>
  <div style="width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
      <div style="float:left:topleft;top:0">
        <h2>L2</h2>
      </div>
      gdgsdgsgsgsgs
      <br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
      <br>gsdgdsgdsgdsgd
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
      <div style="float:left:top:0">
        <h2>R1</h2>
      </div>
      gdgsdgsgsgsgs
      <br>gsgsgsgsdgsg
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
      <div style="float:left:top:0">
        <h2>W1</h2>
      </div>
      gdgsdgsgsgsgs
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```